# Хостинг для приложения c++

Tags: c++, сервер, сокет, хостинг

Не понимаю как работает хостинг. У меня есть простое приложение с сокетами на c++ без всяких c# php mvc. Нужно чтобы это приложение работало на хосте с постоянным ip. Находятся лишь хостинги для сайтов. Подскажите, есть ли такие хостинги, чтобы просто запустить на нем приложение на c++?
P.S. Вопрос корявый, так как сам не понимаю, как задать вопрос. Надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: Ключевые слова для гугла: vds/vps (слабее и дешевле), выделенный сервер (dedicated, дедик) (мощнее и дороже)

Comment: Есть конечно, например AWS бесплатно можно годик погонять..

Answer (score 1):

Хостинг начального уровня, например, мейнстримовый начального уровня Hostgator/Godaddy/Hostinger за 30 долларов в год, не позволяет делать ничего лишнего. Там можно поставить Wordpress или Drupal, и на этом часто все заканчивается. Если вы хотите запускать свои приложения, которые вы сами положите в cgi-bin, вам нужен виртуальный сервер (VDS, VPS). Это стоят дороже, зато там есть саппорт, где помогут решить ваш вопрос.

Если же, предположим, вы желаете протестировать возможности своего приложения в учебных целях, легче изучить вопрос, как запустить сервер на собственном компьютере.